# Header wont display in WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to create a tree header within a `TreeView`, but nothing will display. In my program, I'm creating a series of ellipse objects on a canvas that have names. What I'm trying to do is this:

When the ellipse object is created, create a header within the `TreeView` using the ellipse' names.

Since the first ellipse has a name of "Circle01," this is what I'm trying to display in the `TreeView` when the Left Mouse button is released. But when I do so, nothing happens.

```
// Ellipse object is created when Left Mouse button is release.
private void _canvas_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mouseLBDown)
        {
            mouseLBDown = false;

            if (isCreatingEllipse)
            {
                _debugLabel.Content = "Done.";
                isCreatingEllipse = false;
                loadToTree = true;
            }  
        }
    }

// Suppose to load name of Ellipse as a header, but doesn't.
private void _circleTree_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        if (loadToTree)
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = circle[0].circleName;
            _circleTree.Items.Add(item);
            loadToTree = false;
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
   <TreeView Name="_boneTree" Background="#404040" Foreground="#E0E0E0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Margin="970,28,0,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212" Loaded="_circleTree_Loaded"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not create your own `TreeViewItem`s, rather set the `TreeView`'s `ItemsSource` and let WPF build the `TreeViewItem`s for you. Also it is easier to do this in XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="_boneTree" Background="#404040" Foreground="#E0E0E0"
      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="422" Margin="970,28,0,0"
      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="212"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Circles}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding circleName}"/>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>
```

Where Circles is a property on your DataContext which by default will be your codebehind:

```
public ObservableCollection<Circle> Circles { get; set; }
```

Then whenever a Circle is added or removed it will automatically show up on the UI!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm having trouble on the usage of implementing as ObservableCollection.

Comment: what is the problem, perhaps show some more code, did you remember to create a new one in you constructor?

Comment: here is my class. I think I butchered what you were talking about. My program still does what I intend it to do, but the same problem persists. http://pastebin.com/vLm2vUvs

Comment: You TreeView's ItemSource should be bound to bone (the property). Also each BonePart in the bone collection automatically becomes the DataContext for each TreeViewItem, so you are binding TreeViewItem's Header to BoneName - does BonePart have the a BoneName property?

Comment: Yes, I have a getter/setter for BoneName that's currently set to "bone01"